# Can't make Nginx work with uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, centos6

I am having this test file called `test.py`:

```
def application(env, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b"Hello World"]
```

and I run uWSGI using this command:

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

I am able to see the "Hello World" in browser by going to `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8001`

Now I am trying to add Nginx to this. Here is my file called `mysite_nginx.conf`:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000 default_server;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name _;

    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste





    location /static {
        alias /home/wz/dispatcher/OurAwesomeDjangoApp/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/wz/dispatcher/OurAwesomeDjangoApp/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

When i go to `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` I see the standard "Welcome to Nginx".

However when I go to `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8000` I am unable to connect.

Django server works on this port `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` though.

`uwsgi_params` is present in my project directory.

I have also created a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

What am i missing? Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

When i installed nginx using `yum install nginx` there were no `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories in `/etc/nginx/`.

I created them manually and added:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but maybe removing `default_server` and maybe change the `server_name` to localhost?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.

Comment: Any Nginx error messages in `/var/log/nginx/` (or your custom log file location)?

Comment: In the sites-enabled directory, remove the default file.